# Erro ao ativar WP_DEBUG

Tags: wordpress, debug

Estou com um problema no meu site em WordPress. 
Quando defino no `wp-config.php`, meu site fica normal:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Mas quando defino

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

O site dá erro de página não encontrada. E eu estava precisando debugar porque estou com um outro problema para resolver...

Tem algum problema do wp-debug ficar setado como `true` num servidor Windows?

Estou usando meu website num servidor Windows.

Comment: Por curiosidade, conseguiu solução ou achou o problema?

Comment: A sua reposta me ajudou porque a usei como referência para buscar outra resposta que pudesse me ajudar. Só que agora não lembro como resolvi, eu lembro que me baseei na sua resposta.

Comment: Se em algum momento topar de novo com a solução, ia ser legal se deixasse registrada aqui. Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

A constante WP_DEBUG exibe problemas e alertas relacionados à configurações, plugins e inclusive a segurança, portanto **você não pode deixar ela ativa em um ambiente de produção**.

Quando você define a WP_DEBUG para TRUE, certifique-se de limpar o cache e observar o log de erros de seu site, lá poderão ser exibidas informações sobre o erro 404 (que você alega ser o de página não encontrada).

Você também pode definir seu Wordpress para não trabalhar com URLs amigáveis, nas opções de link permanente, assim deverá evitar os erros 404 que aparentemente são de um problema com o rewrite de seu site. (certifique-se que seu .htaccess está sendo lido corretamente e você não possui *AllowOverride None* nas configurações do seu servidor).

Há um plugin que pode checar isso pra você:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/

Answer (score 1):

Talvez fazendo o debug para um arquivo possa contornar o problema:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false ); // não mostrar na tela
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); // escrever debug em um arquivo
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

Com a constante [`WP_DEBUG_LOG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) ativa, o debug vai ser gerado no arquivo `/wp-content/debug.log`. Esta constante é usada para ver erros de Ajax ou wp-cron que não são mostrados na tela durante a execução do site.

Tempos atrás, fiz um [plugin para visualizar](https://github.com/brasofilo/view-debug-log) esse arquivo diretamente no backend do WordPress.

Se mesmo usando o debug direto para um arquivo seu site continuar sem funcionar por causa dessas constantes, então deve procurar nos logs de erro do seu servidor para ver se há alguma dica do que realmente está acontecendo. Esta solução que apresento é só uma alternativa para contornar o erro real (conflito WP_DEGUB com seu servidor), fiz uma pesquisa rápida e não encontrei nada relacionado.